# Is it possible to print to the screen with a POS-printer?

Tags: vb.net, escaping, opos

I'm searching for a method where I can print something to the screen (in RichTextBox, for example) with a POS-printer.

The method I'm using now is the following: 
I send the string to a method and I paste this string to a RichTextBox, but the textbox doesn't recognize ESCAPE POS codes. So I have to replace these codes with something else.
It would be much easier if I just could print the string (with the ESCAPE POS codes) directly to the screen or textbox.

Some code to explain my problem:

```
Dim ESC As String = Chr(&H1B)
Dim newLine = ESC + "|1lF"

printstring = "Omzet per Locatie-groep/artikel" + newLine
printstring += gTouchSettings.CompanyName + newLine
printstring += newLine
printstring += "Periode: " + Format(fromdate, "dd/MM/yyyy") + " - " +    
                    Format(todate, "dd/MM/yyyy") + newLine
printstring += newLine
printstring += "LocatieGr  Omschrijving   Aantal Ontvangen"
printstring += newLine
printstring += newLine
```

I can erase the newline, I have found the solution for that.
But now I have this layout problem:

```
printstring += Left(MySqlDR!description & Space(27), 27) & 
                   Right("      " &    Format(MySqlDR!quantity, "###0"), 7)
printstring += Right("      " & Format(MySqlDR!item_price, "######0.00"), 8) + 
               newLine
```

This looks great when I print it on a POS printer, but in a TextBox it is horrible.

Comment: Write some code to remove the escape sequences.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the string?

Comment: Thx, I did the following: printString.Replace(escapeCodes, goodCode).
The only problem I still have right now is that if I print to a POS printer, the layout is nice. But if I print to the RichtTextBox, the layout is just horrible... so I still have to figure out something for that.

Comment: If you're generating the string yourself, why not just generate it without the escape codes for the RichTextBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use `String.Format` , it helps with aligning your strings and setting padding etc. check out [These Examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-format-vbnet)